# Input Level Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I developed a little to learn Python.
This one has a level editor. I would like users to have direct access to the level they have created by entering the corresponding number. No interface needs, just an input.
For now the game starts directly at level 1 with the self.level (1), I do not know where to put my input so that the 1 is replaced by the entered value.
Thank you in advance for the help you could provide!

Here is my code :

## This method initializes some attributes: the ball, the bar...

```
def __init__(self, root):
    tk.Canvas.__init__(self, root, bg="#ecf0f1", bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief="ridge", width=self.screenWidth, height=self.screenHeight)
    self.pack()
    self.timeContainer = self.create_text(self.screenWidth/2, self.screenHeight*4/5, text="00:00:00", fill="#bdc3c7", font=("Arial", 15), justify="center")
    self.shield = self.create_rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0, width=0)
    self.bar = self.create_rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0, fill="#7f8c8d", width=0)
    self.ball = self.create_oval(0, 0, 0, 0, width=0)
    self.ballNext = self.create_oval(0, 0, 0, 0, width=0, state="hidden")
    self.level(1)
    self.nextFrame()
```

Comment: You could try something like: `def __init__(self, root, level):` and then in the method `self.level(level)`

Comment: ok then i start the game with this ?  
game = Game(root, level)
root.mainloop()

Comment: You put something like `self.level = input("Which level to play?")` wherever you switch between levels.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi it doesn't work, told me that game is no defined

Comment: With the code you have provided, it is only possible to give you hints. There is no way anybody here can know what your program does when and how. You have to integrate it into your program yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you posted is an initializer aka constructor. It is generally discouraged to do too much work in it. I usually only assign fields, and maybe call some simple methods. You definitely shouldn't ask for user input in the constructor but rather pass parameters to it. You didn't name your class so i'll name it myself:

```
class Some:
    def __init__(self, root, level):
        # all your stuff
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, root, bg="#ecf0f1", bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief="ridge", width=self.screenWidth, height=self.screenHeight)
        # ...
        self.root = root
        self.level = level

# outside your class, where you instantiate it.
level = input('Which level?')
newsome = Some(root, level)
```

Comment: thank you, i did this     def level(self, level):
        self.reset()
        self.levelNum = input("Wich lvl")
        self.bricks = []       and it's work. Thanks a lot for your help everyone !